# Machine learning and Natural Language Processing Algorithms for Indian Surnames Homophones

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, artificial-intelligence

[Homophones](https://www.google.com/search?q=homophones&oq=homophones&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIKCAEQABixAxiABDIKCAIQABixAxiABDIKCAMQABixAxiABDINCAQQABiDARixAxiABDIHCAUQABiABDIKCAYQABixAxiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABDINCAoQABiDARixAxiABDIHCAsQABiABDINCAwQABiDARixAxiABDIHCA0QABiABDIHCA4QABiABNIBCDQyMDFqMGo3qAIAsAIA&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

[Indian Surnames List](https://www.familyeducation.com/baby-names/surname/origin/indian)

[English last names](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/names-last.php)

Can machine learning, Natural Language Processing (NLP), Artificial intelligence assist in classifying , interpreting and specifying the differences homophones in Indian Surnames?